# How to export tangent data of a 3d model from blender

Tags: python, blender

How to export tangent data together with vertex position, normal and uv data of a 3d model from blender.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Blender's API reference](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current) you can find the location of any data you want to export.

You will find that the [mesh data](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Mesh.html) which is stored as `object.data` contains vertices, edges, polygons and loops which holds what you want.

Another option is to look at one of the exporter addons included with blender (like the [obj exporter](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_scene_obj/)) to see where it reads the data from.